# Fast execution of JavaScript when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a dark mode for my WordPress site.

My code in four modes:

1- Based on the user's system

2- Light mode

3- Semi-lit mode

4- Dark mode

It has been placed and works perfectly.

**My problem is that the code is inactive when the page is loaded.**

After loading the page, my code is inactive, and to activate it, you have to click on one of its modes to activate all the scripts. I want my code to be active in whatever state the page is in.

```js
let bodyMode = document.querySelector("#pageMode");
let SystemMode = document.querySelector(".pageSystemMode");
let DarkMode = document.querySelector(".pageDarkMode");
let LightMode = document.querySelector(".pageLightMode");
let HalfLitMode = document.querySelector(".pageHalfLitMode");

SystemMode.addEventListener("click", function () {

    const UserMode = window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;

    if (UserMode) {
        $(bodyMode).addClass("bodyDark");
        $(bodyMode).removeClass("bodyLight bodyHalfLit");
    } else {
        $(bodyMode).removeClass("bodyLight bodyDark bodyHalfLit");
    }

});

DarkMode.addEventListener("click", function () {
    $(bodyMode).addClass("bodyDark");
    $(bodyMode).removeClass("bodyHalfLit");
});

HalfLitMode.addEventListener("click", function () {
    $(bodyMode).addClass("bodyHalfLit");
    $(bodyMode).removeClass("bodyDark");
});

LightMode.addEventListener("click", function () {
    $(bodyMode).addClass("bodyLight");
    $(bodyMode).removeClass("bodyDark bodyHalfLit");
});
```

```css
.main-selectMode {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 2%;
}

a.main-btn {
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 10px;
  direction: rtl;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2512b0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000, 0 0 4px #fff;
}



a.main-btn:hover,
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-check:checked+.btn,
.btn.active,
.btn.show,
.btn:first-child:active,
:not(.btn-check)+.btn:active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #2512b0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #000, 0 0 4px #fff;
}

.main-btn::before {
  margin: 0 7px 0 10px;
}

.main-btn::after {
  margin: 0 10px 0 7px;
}

ul.pageMode li:hover a {
  background: #0058ff;
  color: #fff;
}

ul.pageMode li a {
  direction: rtl;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}

ul.pageMode li a::before {
  margin: 0 7px 0 10px;
}

/* ***************  Mode ******************* */

#pageMode {
  background: #eee;
}

.bodyLight {
  background: #ccc !important;
}

.bodyDark {
  background: #0b0312 !important;
}

.bodyHalfLit {
  background: #777281 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="pageMode">

    <div class="dropdown main-selectMode">
        <a class="fas fa-desktop main-btn btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false">
            Page mode
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu pageMode">
            <li class="SystemMode"><a class="fas fa-desktop pageSystemMode dropdown-item">Assumption</a></li>
            <li class="LightMode"><a class="fas fa-sun pageLightMode dropdown-item">Light mode</a></li>
            <li class="LightMode"><a class="fas fa-cloud-sun pageHalfLitMode dropdown-item">Semi-lit mode</a></li>
            <li class="DarkMode"><a class="fas fa-moon pageDarkMode dropdown-item">Dark mode</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: You should put the default mode into the body of the script... for example: Move the code `SystemMode` click into a function and pass it to the event listener, but also call in immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function for initiating the theme and call it immediately or by click :

```
function initTheme(){

        const UserMode = window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;
    
        if (UserMode) {
            $(bodyMode).addClass("bodyDark");
            $(bodyMode).removeClass("bodyLight bodyHalfLit");
        } else {
            $(bodyMode).removeClass("bodyLight bodyDark bodyHalfLit");
        }
}

//Click listener

SystemMode.addEventListener("click", function () {
   initTheme();
});


//immediate firing:
initTheme();
```

Comment: Hello. Should I put the rest of the modes in the continuation of this code or inside the function?

Comment: For those DarkMode, HalfLitMode and LightMode no need to modify anything. those are click listeners only and no need to be wrapped by a function because you don't need to call them immediately @php